# Running rake:test after installing Raven for Sentry throws an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sentry, raven

After installing [Sentry](https://www.getsentry.com/welcome/) in my Rails 4.1.9 app, their documentation says that I can test if it's installed by running `rake raven:test`. But when I do that, I get this output

```
Sending a test event:
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<Hash:0x007fac6cfc0e70>
```

I've also tried passing in the DSN manually and I get the exact same output. Any reason this isn't working?

edit: I'm assuming that this isn't the test output, but maybe it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Sentry Customer Support:

> The rake:test issue actually looks like something that was missed during a refactor, but it shouldn't be a big deal.